# Combine and transpose multiple single-dimensional arrays into a single multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, transpose

I have three single-dimensional arrays and I need to combine them into one 3-dimensional array where each array in the new array contains one element of each of the three original arrays.

I know how to do this using a simple loop but I was wondering if there is a faster / built-in way of doing this. here is an example of doing this with a loop so you can understand what I'm looking for.

```
function combineArrays(array $array1, array $array2, array $array3) {
    //Make sure arrays are of the same size
    if(count($array1) != count($array2) || count($array2) != count($array3) || count($array1) != count($array3)) {
        throw new Exception("combineArrays expects all paramters to be arrays of the same length");
    }

    //combine the arrays
    $newArray = array();
    for($count = 0; $count < count($array1); $count++) {
        $newArray[] = array($array1[$count], $array2[$count], $array3[$count]);
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = array_map(null,$array1,$array2,$array3);
```